# Laravel performance: pivot tables

Tags: laravel, performance, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I can't find information on this topic:

I'm making some operations on my system that requires getting the ids from users that bought a specific product, so I can do this:

```
foreach($oProduct->users as $oUser){
    HelperClass::registerOperation($oUser->id);
}
```

but this would mean that Laravel needs to create all the User objects just to get the id and then discard all objects.

What would be the best way to get all the user ids directly from the pivot table without having to load hundreds or thousands of objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the ids using `pluck` on the retrieved User collection

```
foreach($oProduct->users->pluck('id') as $oUser){
    HelperClass::registerOperation($oUser);
}
```

Or you can just query the ids from the table itself using Raw SQL.

```
$ids = DB::select('select user_id from product_user where product_id = ?', [$oProduct->id]);
```

Or the QueryBuilder

```
$ids = DB::table('product_user')->select('user_id')
                                ->where('product_id', $oProduct->id)
                                ->get();
```